# Multiline replace in shell

Tags: bash

I have the following chunks of text in a text file:

```
* Exported from Foo *

Title and Section
```

and another

```
* Exported from Foo *

Other Title and Other Section
```

I need to replace this with

```
# Title and Section
```

and

```
# Other Title and Other Section
```

Now, I can do this with:

`echo "$(grep -A 2 "Exported from Foo" ../tmp/data/${nospacefile} | grep -v "Exported from Foo" | grep -v -- -- | tr -d '\r' | grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')" | while read -r title; do sed -i -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*\)$title/\# $title/g" ../tmp/data/${nospacefile}; done`

However, the string "Title and Section" or "Other Title and Other Section" also appears in places I do not want to replace. I only want it replaces if it appears after the Exported line and a blank line.

What's the best shell construct available for me to do this? I am more than happy to send stdout to perl, python, whatever.

Comment: Can yo guarantee that from the line that starts from `* Exported from Foo *` it is always the third line that needs to be edited? The second being the empty line and it is always from the beginning of the line?

Comment: Yes, it's always the third line (but it has random text) . Basically I want to replace the random text with "# random text"

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ed(1)`, This edit the third line starting from `* Exported from Foo *` regardless if the second line is empty or not.

To just print the output to `stdout` like sed

```bsh
printf '%s\n' 'g/^\* Exported from Foo \*$/+2s/^/# /' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

That just prints the output to `stdout`, to edit the file in place.

```bsh
printf '%s\n' 'g/^\* Exported from Foo \*$/+2s/^/# /' w | ed -s file.txt
```

To use an `ed` script that just print the output to `stdout`

```
cat script.ed
```

Output

```
g/^\* Exported from Foo \*$/+2s/^/# /
,p
Q
```

The script that edit the file `in-place`

```
g/^\* Exported from Foo \*$/+2s/^/# /
w
q
```

Now you can do

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Of course, I found I also had \r\n in my file, so I had to delete the \r's...

Comment: It is easy to remove the `\r` using Unix tools such as `dos2unix`, glad you have it working.

Comment: I just used "tr -d '\r' " as I was too lazy to install dos2unix on my mac... as I already had to brew install a bunch of utilities as the mac utils are so old that I kept getting syntax errors in other parts. 8-)

Comment: On my `FreeBSD` `ed` is installed by default so It should be in your `mac`.

Comment: It is. Now I'm waiting the 3 hours it takes to convert all of my text files to PDF via pandoc.

Comment: OK, now I'd like to extend this to a one-liner if possible.
Instead of just inserting # before the Text, I'd like to do an insert before and after the text, so something like
Text

to

# Text \foo

Comment: `printf '%s\n' 'g/^\* Exported from Foo \*$/+2s/^\(.\+\)$/\# \1 \\bar/' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt`

Comment: Excellent. I ended up just doing an extra sed step afterwards, but I'll replace it with this.. because. Thx.